# FlexibleSpaceBar avoid system interface

Tags: flutter

How can avoid system interface using NestedScrollView and FlexibleSpacebar? also, Is there a way to hide one FlexibleSpacebar behaind other?
I want to create a appBar collapses when scrolling and show more filters

Here are some images with the problem and my code

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
  body: NestedScrollView(
    floatHeaderSlivers: true,
    headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
      return <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          expandedHeight: 220.0,
          pinned: true,
          floating: true,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            expandedTitleScale: 1,
            centerTitle: true,
            title: TextFormField(
              onSaved: (value) {},
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                hintText: "title",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                  borderSide: BorderSide()),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                  borderSide: BorderSide()),
                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search))),
          ),
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            expandedTitleScale: 1,
            centerTitle: true,
            title: TextFormField(
              onSaved: (value) {},
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                hintText: "Search items...",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                  borderSide: BorderSide()),
                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)))))
      ];
    },
    body: const Center(
      child: Text(
        "This is body",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)))));
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use Stack but best will be using SliverPersistanceHeader IMO

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate`.

```dart
class MySliverPersistanceDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.deepPurple,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: lerpDouble(20, -80, shrinkOffset / maxExtent),
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: titleWidget(),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: SearchItems(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 220.0;

  @override
  double get minExtent => kToolbarHeight;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) =>
      false;
}
```

And use

```dart
body: NestedScrollView(
    floatHeaderSlivers: true,
    headerSliverBuilder:
        (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
      return <Widget>[
        SliverPersistentHeader(
          delegate: MySliverPersistanceDelegate(),
          pinned: true,
        )
      ];
    },
```

Also CustomScrollView will be a great choice.